# Error: Cannot find module, but only on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

My application runs just fine locally, and on a Travis CI build server but when its on Heroku

I get `Error: Cannot find module` and the app crashes.

Some facts about the npm module

- it lives on github
- its a private repo
- its accessed like this `"my_module": "git+https://MY_KEY:x-oauth-basic@github.com/me/my_module#develop"`

Edit:

It seems that Heroku is erroneously removing my module after the build

```
-----> Pruning unused dependencies
   unbuild my_module@0.0.7
-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this was due to my local dev machine (OSX) not being fussy about the casing of file paths whereas Heroku (linux) is.

My module was installed to `node_modules/mymodule` instead of `node_modules/myModule` as it should have been.

Comment: Did you solve the issue on your local machine? if yes then could you share how?